# detect network malicious activity coming from own linux server

Tags: linux, networking, security, ubuntu, network-monitor

I have a VPS provider that is strictly disallows malicious activity like ssh-bruting, ddos, and such.

I also have multiple users that use the single VPS machine, each allocated to one docker container.

The problem is I do not know if the users are doing anything malicious other than to check the CPU usage and do tcpdump.

Is there a program that listens on the network's outgoing that makes sure the users aren't doing anything malicious?